# How do I specify which APIs should be generated by swagger codegen

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-codegen

I want to generate a rest API with swagger codegen, but I have a big yaml with much more Models and APIs than needed.
So I want selective generate my Rest Service.
I have the following lines added to my pom.xml for restriction:

```
<models>MyModelA,MyModelB</models>
<apis>MyAApi,MyBApi</apis>
```

The models line work, only model A and B where generated. But the APIs don't seem to work, no APIs where generated. Am I using the wrong syntax? Should I pass the resource path into the APIs tag or the API name?